# What causes REPL to print a function signature instead of function result?

Tags: f#

**What causes the REPL to print a function signature instead of function result?**

I am attempting to execute the following line:

```
let email = Email "abc.com";;
email |> sendMessage |> ignore;;
```

**The code is as follows**

```
type PhoneNumber = 
    { CountryCode:int
      Number:string }

type ContactMethod =
    | Email of string
    | PhoneNumber of PhoneNumber

let sendMessage contact = function
    | Email _ -> printf "Sending message via email"
    | PhoneNumber phone -> printf "Sending message via phone"

// c. Create two values, one for the email address case and 
// one for the phone number case, and pass them to sendMessage.
let email = Email "abc.com";;
email |> sendMessage |> ignore;;
```

**I get the following result:**

```
type PhoneNumber =
  {CountryCode: int;
   Number: string;}
type ContactMethod =
  | Email of string
  | PhoneNumber of PhoneNumber
val sendMessage : contact:'a -> _arg1:ContactMethod -> unit
val email : ContactMethod = Email "abc.com"

>
val it : unit = ()
```

**I expected something like this:**

> "Sending message via email"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `sendMessage` function takes **two** arguments: one named `contact` of unrestricted type `'a` and an anonymous (`_arg1` in the signature) `ContactMethod`.

When you supply `email` to `sendMessage` you get a function which takes a `ContactMethod` and returns `unit`. You then `ignore` this function.

Either remove the `contact` parameter (more idiomatic):

```
let sendMessage = function
    | Email _ -> printf "Sending message via email"
    | PhoneNumber phone -> printf "Sending message via phone"
```

or match on it (might be easier to understand):

```
let sendMessage contact =
    match contact with
    | Email _ -> printf "Sending message via email"
    | PhoneNumber phone -> printf "Sending message via phone"
```

Now, `sendMessage` is of type `ContactMethod -> unit` and you don't need to `ignore` anymore.

Comment: Rule of thumb. If you ever have to use `ignore` and don't know why, then take a serious look at the function signature, odds are that you have a potential bug lurking in the code. I find that `ignore` is used a lot more with calls to .NET code than F# functions, especially when .NET code has a side effect, e.g. `StringBuilder append`, and you need the side effect but not the result of the call.

Comment: Also if you ever use `Press any key to continue` then you would use `Console.ReadKey() |> ignore`; again you need the side effect but not the result.